# "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

Tags: c#

```
try
{
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand komanda = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = konekcija;
        command.CommandText = "insert into EmployeeData (FirstName,LastName,Pay) values('"+txt_fname.Text+"','"+txt_lname.Text+"','"+txt_pay.Text+"')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("data saved");
        connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
       MessageBox.Show("error"+ex);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use parameterized queries

Comment: i assume you have a `'` character in one of your textboxes

Comment: Please set *break point* on `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` line and provide *actual* `command.CommandText` value

Comment: datatype of pay is currency

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you don't actually *know* what query you're executing.  Because you're executing *any code that your users send you*.

In most non-edge cases this *appears* to "work just fine" (which is why it often goes unnoticed), in some cases it causes a syntax or structural error in the query (which is what's happening here), and in some cases users take advantage of it to execute arbitrary code on your database.

This is called a [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) vulnerability.

You'd correct this by using query parameters which treat user input as *values* instead of as *executable code*.  Something like this:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into EmployeeData (FirstName,LastName,Pay) values(?,?,?)";
command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_fname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_lname.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@Pay", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_pay.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that I've guessed on the `OleDbType` and size of the columns.  Adjust as necessary for your table structure.

Comment: Ole DB provider doesn't support named parameters - you should use `?` in the `CommandText` (and make sure, as you have already done here, that the parameters are added to the `Parameters` collection in the correct order)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i've fixed that, and now i'm getting the" "Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value" error", but everything seems correct to me

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Interesting, I'm finding examples online either way.  Admittedly I don't have an opportunity to test at the moment.

Comment: @M.M: It would appear that the primary key in that table doesn't auto-generate a value.  Either it needs to, or you'd need to supply a value when inserting a record.  (The auto-generate option is often preferred.)

Comment: command.CommandText ="insert into EmployeeData (FirstName,LastName,Pay) values(@FirstName,@LastName,@Pay)"; I've tried it like this,change only this one line of code, and it works. Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: No definitive sources? [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx): "The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Very strange, my Google search was finding other MSDN articles which had examples containing named parameters.  (Likely confusion somewhere between that and `SqlCommand`.)  Either way, answer's been updated.  Thanks!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe _some_ OleDb providers _allow_ you to use named parameters, but they still bind the parameter collection based on the order that they're added, so the names are useless.  So the use of "must" may be more restrictive that what's actually allowed.